# Oracle SecureFiles LOBs Licencing

Tags: oracle, security, blob, license

We argued in our DBA team on whether an Oracle Database with SecureFiles LOBs needs to be an Enterprise Edition. Can I use Oracle Secure File Lobs in a Standard Edition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Securefile LOBs are free to use in any edition.

Only the extra features of Securefile LOBs require buying the Advanced Compression or Advanced Security option, and these options are available only in Enterprise Edition.

These features are:

Advanced Compression: Securefile compression and deduplication.

Advanced Security: Securefile encryption.

[Licensing Information](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/dblic/Licensing-Information.html)

[image]

Comment: 18c XE includes many EE features including Adv. Compression.  But, that is probably there so you are forced to EE ($$$) after you hit the 12GB limit.